# R Entire plot titles in Greek

Tags: r, plot, title

I would like to write entire plot titles in Greek.

Several posts deal with including sole Greek letters within plot titles, axis titles, etc, but I would like the entire title to be in Greek (because the charts will be presented to Greek audience).

For example:

```
p <- c(50,50)
pie(p, labels = c("Κείμενο στα Ελληνικά"," Some English characters"), main = paste0("Επιπλέον Ελληνικά ", "More English"))
```

And here's the result I get:
[image]

Only some of the Greek characters are displayed correctly.
I tried reopening my code with several different encodings but with no luck.

Thank you

Comment: I can't see the problem. If you want the entire main title to be in Greek, why not just write it in Greek? Sorry if this is utterly beyond the point (but maybe you haven't made your point clear enough)

Comment: I apologize, I should have mentioned it, when I write the title in Greek only some characters appear correctly. It seems like an encoding problem but I cannot say for sure. Any changes in character encoding I tried did not work.

Comment: You should state R version and platform.  For the record, your Greek labels appear fine on my MacOS system running R 4.0.0.

Comment: True, same for me.

Comment: I just updated to R 4.0.0 and RStudio 1.2.5042 but unfortunately I still get the same graph. I run Windows 10 64bit.